# Registration program open source

Tags: linux, ubuntu, software-rec

Is there an open source program for registering people at gatherings, and events. I would like to register them, and even combine a photo for a name tag. And at the same time, having a record.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, i've never heard of one but if what you want to do is not very complex you can probably accomplish it using a simple database. Since you've tagged this as ubuntu you might wanna try openoffice/libreoffice Base.
Not quite the answer you were looking for but it's a valid solution if you can't find the desired software.

Comment: Thanks Solo, I think you are right, and getting me thinking - which is a good thing! It would be like a database, and I had one set up in FileMaker Pro but it will not run in Linux. I would think there would be a stand alone program for this but I, likewise, have not found one. Thanks